# Detect option that currently scroll at in select element - webView iOS

Tags: ios, mobile

Currently, I'm having a problem with the select element in webView iOS.

I wonder if there is a way to detect which option that the user is currently scroll at, not yet selected (click on "Done" button). Or maybe an event when user tap ">" button on the keyboard.

[image]

My scenario is that I need to detect which value user select on Profession, which will determine show/hide of the Employer field next to it.

So when the user click ">" then it should show the Employer field and navigate to that field.

Which it does now is navigate and to the "Gross annual salary in CHF" and then show the field "Employer" and hide the keyboard as it detects new input element.

The web is implemented by JSF + Primefaces.

Comment: The fact that IOS does not include JSF does not mean it is not (necessarily) related. WebView is/can be used to display websites/webapplications designed in any technology (php, jsf, .Net mvc any client-side hyped javascript framework). The OP even explicitly mentions this as the last  It might be that the JSF (or rather PrimeFaces) select element does not work IN IOS webview but does work in e.g. the 'Android' webview (should be good if the OP mentioned things like this).

Comment: Please show code in [mcve] format. The JSF tag is removed but that might have been wrong. Currently the question is unanswerable